# Required explanation on old regular expression code

Tags: java, regex

I came across an old code written by myself several years ago. However, right now, I have no idea why it works. I need to understand why it work, before I proceed for code changes.

I have data in CSV format

```
"abc",123456789,"def"
```

Sometimes, the server will return me

```
"abc",123,456,789,"def"
```

So, I wrote the following code to resolve it.

```
public class Sandbox {

    private static final Pattern digitPattern = Pattern.compile("(\",)|,(?=[\\d,]+,\")");
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // "abc",123,456,789,"def"
        String data = "\"abc\",123,456,789,\"def\"";

        final String result = digitPattern.matcher(data).replaceAll("$1");

        // "abc",123456789,"def"
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

However, when I look back at the code, I have no idea why `|,` and `[\\d,]+` able to help me remove the comma. Which portion of input is `|,` matching to?

Step by step explanation on how the parsing work is very much appreciated

Comment: If you want to delete all commas with a digit before and after it, why don't you use `data = data.replaceAll("(\\d),(\\d)", "$1$2");` ?

Comment: `|` is an OR, as in match what's before it OR what's after it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are replacing

```
(\",)|,(?=[\\d,]+,\")
```

with

```
$1
```

In other words, you're **leaving any commas immediately following double-quotes alone** (that's the `(\",)`, captured into `$1`), but **removing commas that are followed by 1 or more numbers and commas, a comma, and a double-quote** (that's the lookahead assertion, `(?=[\\d,]+,\")`). With alternation (`|`), it's left-to-right precedence, so if the first half is matched, *i.e.* the comma immediately follows a double-quote, then that's that, so the engine moves on, looking for the next comma. If the second half is matched, `$1` isn't captured, so effectively you are replacing your match (the comma) with an empty string.